# Why RegAsm add 'W' on some method signatures?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, com, c++-cli, com-interop

I'm writting a C++/CLI project with COM Interop to expose methods and objects for a VBA client.

All was good until now, but I encounter a strange issue: some methods are exported with an (unwanted) 'W' suffix (e.g. `GetUserNameW`)!

Let me explain in details...

I have a utility class wrote like this:

**MyUtils.h**

```
#pragma once

namespace MyApp {

    [System::Runtime::InteropServices::ComVisible(true)]
    [System::Runtime::InteropServices::Guid("...guid...")]
    [System::Runtime::InteropServices::InterfaceType(System::Runtime::InteropServices::ComInterfaceType::InterfaceIsDual)]
    public interface class IMyUtils
    {
        System::String^ CombinePaths(System::String^ path1, System::String^ path2);
        System::String^ GetDocumentsDirectory();
        System::String^ GetMachineName();
        System::String^ GetSystemDirectory();
        System::String^ GetUserName();
    };

    [System::Runtime::InteropServices::ComVisible(true)]
    [System::Runtime::InteropServices::Guid("...another guid...")]
    [System::Runtime::InteropServices::ClassInterface(System::Runtime::InteropServices::ClassInterfaceType::None)]
    public ref class MyUtils : IMyUtils
    {
    public:
        MyUtils();

        virtual System::String^ CombinePaths(System::String^ path1, System::String^ path2);

        virtual System::String^ GetDocumentsDirectory();

        virtual System::String^ GetMachineName();

        virtual System::String^ GetSystemDirectory();

        virtual System::String^ GetUserName();
    };
}
```

**MyUtils.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MyUtils.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

namespace MyApp
{
    MyUtils::MyUtils()
    {
        // Do nothing...
    }

    String^ MyUtils::CombinePaths(String^ path1, String^ path2)
    {
        return Path::Combine(path1, path2);
    }

    String^ MyUtils::GetDocumentsDirectory()
    {
        return Environment::GetFolderPath(Environment::SpecialFolder::MyDocuments);
    }

    String^ MyUtils::GetMachineName()
    {
        return Environment::MachineName;
    }

    String^ MyUtils::GetSystemDirectory()
    {
        return Environment::SystemDirectory;
    }

    String^ MyUtils::GetUserName()
    {
        return Environment::UserName;
    }
}
```

Nothing difficult here.

Then, I create the TLB and register the assembly with this command line:

```
regasm MyLib.dll /codebase /tlb
```

Now, when I try to use the object on the VBA client, I have this:

```
Dim utils As New MWUtils

utils.CombinePaths "C:\Windows", "System32"
utils.GetDocumentsDirectory
utils.GetMachineName
utils.GetSystemDirectoryW '<== What?
utils.GetUserNameW '<== Again?
```

Notice the 'W' suffix on `GetSystemDirectory` and `GetUserName` methods!

Intermediary question: Where does it come from?

Ok, look into the generated IDL for the interface:

```
[
  uuid(...guid...),
  dual,
  oleautomation
]
interface IMyUtils : IDispatch {
    [id(0x60020000)] 
    HRESULT CombinePaths(
        [in] BSTR path1,
        [in] BSTR path2,
        [out, retval] BSTR* pRetVal
    );
    [id(0x60020001)] 
    HRESULT GetDocumentsDirectory([out, retval] BSTR* pRetVal);
    [id(0x60020002)] 
    HRESULT GetMachineName([out, retval] BSTR* pRetVal);
    [id(0x60020003)] 
    HRESULT GetSystemDirectoryW([out, retval] BSTR* pRetVal);
    [id(0x60020004)] 
    HRESULT GetUserNameW([out, retval] BSTR* pRetVal);

};
```

It's is clear now that the RegAsm tool has alter the signatures of the methods, but **why**?

'W' suffix indicate an Unicode string, but it's the first time that I see this kind of alteration!

Final question #1: **Why RegAsm indicates Unicode strings for these two methods?**

Final question #2: **How can I suppress this "alteration"?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using identifiers that are also in use by the Windows winapi.  Like GetUserName() and GetSystemDirectory().  These winapi functions exist in two versions, the W version takes a Unicode string and the A version takes a legacy 8-bit string.  To make this work, the SDK header contains *macros* to rename GetUserName() to GetUserNameW() if the UNICODE macro is defined.

The standard problem with macros is that they are not selective, *every* identifier named "GetUserName" will be renamed.  Including yours.

Two basic ways to tackle this problem:

- Pick another name, less accidents in the client code that way as well when it is written in C or C++.
- Add `#undef GetUserName` after your #include for the winapi headers so this macro is disabled.  Repeat as necessary.

Comment: Very subtle. One more trap of C++/CLI that doesn't exist with C#. So, I add `#undef GetUserName` and `#undef GetSystemDirectory` after including stdafx.h but BEFORE including MyUtils.h and it works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It's not RegAsm that's modifying your assembly, it's being compiled that way in the first place.

If you look in Windows.h, you'll see that there's two signatures for each method that can take a string as a parameter: `FooMethodA` that takes a `char*`, and `FooMethodW` that takes a `wchar_t*`. ('A' and 'W' stand for ASCII and Widechar.) However, you're not required to type the trailing 'A' or 'W', just the name of the method: This is accomplished with a `#define`. For each method that takes a string, `FooMethod` is `#define`ed to either `FooMethodA` or `FooMethodW`.

Since a `#define` is a raw text substitution, it affects everything. Including methods declared inside your class that happen to share the name of a Windows API, [GetSystemDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724373.aspx) and [GetUserName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724432.aspx).

To fix this, `#undef` GetSystemDirectory and GetUserName. If you need to use those methods, call the real names explicitly, `GetSystemDriectoryW` and `GetUserNameW`.

Comment: 'A' is for ANSI rather than ASCII.